# How to run another method beside application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, parallel-processing, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I want to be able to run another global method which will continue execution while the user navigates through the pages.

So I made a task in `App.xaml`:

```
public static Task globalTask = null;
```

and then:

```
public App()
{
    ...
    globalTask = Update();
}
```

and `Update()` method is this:

```
public async Task Update()
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Second % 5 == 0)
            await db.InsertCurrentTime(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

but when I debug, I see that `Update()` isn't working continuously.

the question is: How can I make the `Update()` method just continue working while the app is running? No matter, with `async` `await` or in another way.

*Note: this is a simplified version of what I'm doing, unnecessary things removed*

Comment: You need to either run Update in another thread (bad idea, will eat up tons of CPU) or put a awaitable pause in your Update method. you should have gotten a compiler warning for using `async` without using `await`. Also questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself. See [SSCCE.org](http://SSCCE.org) for guidance. With your quote "*this is a simplified version of what I'm doing, unnecessary things removed*" it is hard to tell if you are awaiting or not.

Comment: thanks @ScottChamberlain. I have updated it. also with `await` it doesn't continue working. I see it goes through the last statement `await db.InsertCu...` but never continue again.

Comment: Well that means `db.InsertCurrentTime` never completes. You will need to show the code for that. That is why we ask for a SSCCE, please create a simple example that replicates the problem and include ***all*** of the code to re-create the problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain He could be blocking the UI somewhere else, causing the classic `await` deadlock.  That would stop the loop from continuing.

Comment: @Servy Good point, did not think of that, that is a common mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are several issues here.

First, an `async` method simply allows the use of `await` within the method.  It doesn't automatically make the method run in another thread.  When this method is called the caller will run the method synchronously until it hits an `await` and then run the rest of the method as a continuation of the awaited task.  Since you have no await, and you have an infinite loop, it means that calling this method just results in the caller blocking forever.

Next, your code *seems* to be intended to run some code once every 5 seconds, but it doesn't do that.  Instead, it runs the given block of code *as many times as it possibly can* in one out of every five seconds.  Now it seems that the operation is inserting something into a database, which it may well be able to do a few times per second.  If you had a faster operation it may well be able to do it millions of times in a single second.  That's probably bad.  You don't want to do that.

Oh, and it also has the problem that it's possible for the thread to go an entire second without ever being scheduled.  One would hope that it wouldn't be happening in general, as that's a long time for a computer, but it is technically possible for an entire iteration to be skipped.

Another problem is that you're doing a busy wait.  In 4 out of 5 seconds your code is sitting there spinning around in its `while` loop as fast as it possibly can, skipping the `if` block each time.  This is wasting tons and tons of CPU time for literally zero benefit.

So while you may be able to find a way of moving this to another thread, you don't want to do that.  Instead, just use a `Timer` and set the interval to 5 seconds to run some code every 5 seconds reliably and efficiently.

If you want to use `await`, then you can do something like this:

```
public async Task Update()
{
    while (true)
    {
        db.InsertCurrentTime(DateTime.Now);
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
            .ConfigureAwait(false);//remove if you want the UI context
    }
}
```

This then ensures that you are running the block of code once every 5 seconds, and that you're not performing a busy wait for those 5 seconds but rather making the method properly asynchronous and having each iteration of the loop schedule a continuation to run in 5 seconds.